# Excel VBA - Loop not adding autofilters to my worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that (should) loop through all my worksheets and add an autofilter, however for some reason they're not showing up. When I turn on events, I can see that it is quickly being added then removed almost instantly. I'm assuming that this is because of something written earlier in my code, but I have too much code before this to evaluate what is causing the issue... Is there something I can add to guarantee the filters are added? Code:

```
Dim wsfixer As Worksheet
    For Each wsfixer In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
With ActiveSheet
       .AutoFilterMode = False
       .Range("A:S").AutoFilter
End With
On Error Resume Next
   Next
```

Comment: For starters i'd disable all error handling - perhaps there's an error somewhere causing your other issues,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process the code on each worksheet, change

```
With ActiveSheet
```

to

```
With wsfixer
```

By using `With ActiveSheet` the code within the `With` block is being "shortcutted" to using the active sheet (e.g. `.AutoFilterMode` is treated as `ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode`).  So you are executing the same code over and over to the one active sheet.

Comment: I literally just laughed out loud (I'm such a fool!). I've never been that good with loops... thanks for the swift response!